# Replacing a line in a csv file?

Tags: linux, command-line

I have a set of 10 CSV files, which normally have a an entry of this kind

```
a,b,c,d
d,e,f,g
```

Now due to some error entries in this file have become of this kind

```
a,b,c,d
d,e,f,g
,,,
h,i,j,k
```

Now I want to remove the line with only commas in all the files. These files are on a Linux filesystem.

Any command that you recommend that can replaces the erroneous lines in all the files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by replace.  If you mean 'remove', then a trivial variant on @wnoise's solution is:

```
grep -v '^,,,$' old-file.csv > new-file.csv
```

Note that this deletes just those lines with exactly three commas.  If you want to delete mal-formed lines with any number of commas (including zero) - and no other characters on the line, then:

```
grep -v '^,*$' ...
```

There are endless other variations on the regex that would deal with other scenarios.  Dealing with full CSV data with commas inside quotes starts to need something other than a regex machine.  It can be done, within broad limits, especially in more complex regex systems such as PCRE or Perl.  But it requires more work.

Check out [Mastering Regular Expressions](http://regex.info/).

Answer (score 2):

```
sed 's/,,,/replacement/' < old-file.csv > new-file.csv
```

optionally followed by 
    mv new-file.csv old-file.csv

Comment: O.M.G! Kickin' it old skool! It makes me feel ooolllldddd. :-)

Comment: doesn't remove the line... see David's for better use of sed

Comment: It asked for replacement, not removal when I answered.

Comment: @Peter, it's not old school it's classic
@orip it's a fine use of sed

Comment: In wnoise's defense, it did say replace at first; see the edit history.  And this sed usage is portable across platforms; notations using '-i' are specific to GNU sed (and hence valid for the question which is about files on Linux).

Answer (score 1):

Replace or remove, your post is not clear... For replacement see wnoise's answer.  For removing, you could use

```
awk '$0 !~ /,,,/ {print}' <old-file.csv > new-file.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to replace them with something, or delete them entirely?  Either way, it can be done with `sed`.  To delete:

```
sed -i -e '/^,\+$/ D' yourfile1.csv yourfile2.csv ...
```

To replace: well, see wnoise's answer, or if you don't want to create new files with the output,

```
sed -i -e '/^,\+$/ s//replacement/' yourfile1.csv yourfile2.csv ...
```

or

```
sed -i -e '/^,\+$/ c\
replacement' yourfile1.csv yourfile2.csv ...
```

(that should be entered exactly as is, including the line break).  Of course, you can also do this with `awk` or `perl` or, if you're only deleting lines, even `grep`:

```
egrep -v '^,+$' < oldfile.csv > newfile.csv
```

I tested these to make sure they work, but I'd advise you to do the same before using them (just in case).  You can omit the `-i` option from `sed`, in which case it'll print out the results (rather than writing them back to the file), or omit the output redirection `>newfile.csv` from `grep`.

*EDIT:* It was pointed out in a comment that some features of these `sed` commands only work on GNU `sed`.  As far as I can tell, these are the `-i` option (which can be replaced with shell redirection, `sed ... <infile >outfile` ) and the `\+` modifier (which can be replaced with `\{1,\}` ).

Comment: Some of your 'sed' options are not portable (GNU sed specific).  Not a major problem as long as you're aware of that.

Comment: @Johnathan: true, I only ever use GNU sed and I tend to forget about its extensions unless I'm actually staring at the info page.  Thanks.

Comment: @Dahvid :D  The question did say "Linux file system" - your answer is valid given that constraint.

Answer (score 1):

What about trying to keep only lines which are matching the desired format instead of handling one exception ?

If the provided input is what you really want to match:

```
grep -E '[a-z],[a-z],[a-z],[a-z]' < oldfile.csv > newfile.csv
```

If the input is different, provide it, the regular expression should not be too hard to write.

Answer (score 1):

Most simply:

```
$   grep -v ,,,, oldfile > newfile   
$   mv newfile oldfile
```

Comment: Only 3 commas in pattern to be removed. :D

Answer (score 0):

yes, awk or grep are very good option if you are working in linux platform. However you can use perl regex for other platform. using join & split options.

Comment: Why split and join?  Yes, you can certainly use perl.  But the basic loop would be using a regex to match or not match the lines to be printed - I don't see the join/split operation.  Even a replacement instead of a delete probably wouldn't use join or split.